# Bolding Math Acronyms

Tags: math-mode, bold, acronyms

I need to have the math acronyms bolded as the normal string acronyms. Here is the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\makeglossary

\begin{document}

Hello, here are the acronyms: \ac{MA} and \ac{$M^{2}_c$}

\begin{acronym}

    \acro{$M^{2}_c$}{My Math Customized Acronym}
    \acro{MA}{My Acronym}

\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Any idea how to have the $M^{2}_c$ abbreviation bolded in the final acronym list (as the MA for example)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's better not to use a math formula in the first argument of `\acro`, but you can have it in the optional argument, as in

```
\acro{M2C}[$\bm{M^{2}_c}$]{My Math Customized Acronym}
```

which uses the `\bm` command from the same package to have bold math.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\makeglossary

\begin{document}

Hello, here are the acronyms: \ac{MA} and \ac{M2C}

\begin{acronym}

    \acro{M2C}[$\bm{M^{2}_c}$]{My Math Customized Acronym}
    \acro{MA}{My Acronym}

\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Anyway this bolds the reference as well.

Using

```
\renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{\bm{\textbf{\acsfont{#1}}}}
```

solves this problem

MWE (With upright math as per your comment)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\makeglossary

\renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{\bm{\textbf{\acsfont{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

Hello, here are the acronyms: \ac{MA} and \ac{M2C}

\begin{acronym}

    \acro{M2C}[$\mathrm{M}^{2}_\mathrm{c}$]{My Math Customized Acronym}
    \acro{MA}{My Acronym}

\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: do you know if it is possible to remove the italic shape (only in the acronyms section, without affecting the rest in your document for the formulas)?

Comment: @schmi `\mathrm{M}^2`

Comment: @schmi Yes, it is. See the second part of the answer.

Comment: The second way fails for me with error: \aclabelfont undefined

Comment: @schmi Surely you have an outdated version of `acronym` package. Try updating it.

Comment: Wow I would never have guessed the construct `\bm{$h$}` worked (and I wrote it:-) Actually even now I'm not quite sure how it worked. `\boldmath` as in my answer would be much safer and quicker:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Neither I would have guessed that...

Answer (score 5):

Just tell the package to use `\boldmath` as well as `\textbf`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{\textbf{\boldmath\acsfont{#1}}}

\begin{document}

Hello, here are the acronyms: \ac{MA} and \ac{$M^{2}_c$}

\begin{acronym}

    \acro{$M^{2}_c$}{My Math Customized Acronym}
    \acro{MA}{My Acronym}

\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```