# Math acronym using acro package

Tags: math-mode, bold, acro

I am using "acro" package for defining acronyms. I displayed the list of notations I used in my document and below is my code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{acro,times}
\acsetup{first-style=short}
\DeclareAcronym{mg2+}{
    short = \ensuremath{Mg^{2+}},
    long = Magnesium ion,
    class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{GMC}{
    short = GMC,
    long = G. M. Constructions,
    class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{Au}{
    short = Au,
    long = Gold,
    class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{mL}{
    short = mL,
    long = milli litre,
    class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{cl-}{
    short = \ensuremath{Cl^{-}},
    long = Chloride ion,
    class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{br-}{
    short = \ensuremath{Br^{-}},
    long = Bromide ion,
    class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{L}{
    short = L,
    long = Litre,
    class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{m3}{
    short = \ensuremath{m^3},
    long = Meter cube,
    class = nomencl
}
\begin{document}

    I love \ac{mg2+} because it is healthy. \ac{Au} is very great metal. A stock solution of other ions like $\ac{cl-}$ (sodium chloride), $\ac{br-}$ (potassium bromide) is prepared by dissolving their respective salts in $100$ \ac{mL} water. $1$ \ac{m3} = $1000$ \ac{L}
    \printacronyms[include-classes=nomencl,name=Notations]
\end{document}
```

I got the following output:
[image]

Here we can see that those acronyms with `\ensuremath{}` in their short forms are displayed with normal characters in the list of notations. Whereas, those acronym without `\ensuremath{}` in their short forms are displayed in bold characters in the list of notations. How to prevent this behavior and display short forms of all the acronyms in bold characters in the list of notations. Same problem in `acronym` package is solved here in this [Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229930/bolding-math-acronyms). Is there any way solve this problem in `acro` package? Any suggestion/feedback will be of great help.

Comment: Don't use math mode for the chemical formulas, use the `chemformula` or the `mhchem` package (italic formulas are wrong, anyway)

Comment: For units, the `siunitx` package can be used.

Comment: @leandriis I tried ```siunitx``` package for the ```$m^3$``` but still the short form of ```$m^3$``` in the list of notation is not shown in bold letter. I used ```\si{\cubic\meter}``` instead of ```$m^3$```. When tried ```m\ensuremath{^\text{3}}``` it is shown in bold character as shown in my answer. I don't why.!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @cgnieder for your feedback. I used `mhchem` package to write chemical formulas instead of using math environment. By doing so, the problem was solved.

Here is the code using `mhchem` package which gives my expected result:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{acro,times,mhchem}
\acsetup{first-style=short}
\DeclareAcronym{mg2+}{
    short = \ce{Mg^2+},
    long = Magnesium ion,
    class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{GMC}{
    short = GMC,
    long = G. M. Constructions,
    class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{Au}{
    short = Au,
    long = Gold,
    class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{mL}{
    short = mL,
    long = milli litre,
    class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{cl-}{
    short = \ce{Cl^-},
    long = Chloride ion,
    class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{br-}{
    short = \ce{Br^{-}},
    long = Bromide ion,
    class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{L}{
    short = L,
    long = Litre,
    class = nomencl
}
\DeclareAcronym{m3}{
    short = m\ensuremath{^\text{3}},
    long = Meter cube,
    class = nomencl
}
\begin{document}

    I love \ac{mg2+} because it is healthy. \ac{Au} is very great metal. A stock solution of other ions like \ac{cl-} (sodium chloride), $\ac{br-}$ (potassium bromide) is prepared by dissolving their respective salts in $100$ \ac{mL} water. $1$ \ac{m3} = $1000$ \ac{L}
    \printacronyms[include-classes=nomencl,name=Notations]
\end{document}
```

And the result is:
[image]